# Express Matrix 1-norm into other matrix operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a square matrix $A$,

The Forbenius norm $||A||_F$ can be expressed into $\sqrt{Tr(AA^T)}$

Is there are similar expression of matrix one norm $||A||_1$?

Answer (score 1):

The $\Vert \cdot \Vert_1$ and  $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty}$ of a matrix can be computed relatively easily (with $\mathcal{O}(mn)$ computational effort), using the formulas below.
$$\Vert A \Vert_1 = \max_{j=1,2,\ldots,n} \sum_{i=1}^m \vert a_{ij} \vert$$ i.e., the maximum absolute column sum of the matrix.

$$\Vert A \Vert_1 = \max_{i=1,2,\ldots,m} \sum_{j=1}^n \vert a_{ij} \vert$$ i.e., the maximum absolute row sum of the matrix.

Comment: The question may not be clear enough, I mean matrix/vector operation. Anyway thanks for giving the definition, I forgot to provide this in my problem.

Comment: @Rein What I gave is not the definition, though it follows from the definition. The definition of $1$ norm is $$\max_{\Vert x \Vert_1} \Vert Ax \Vert_1$$ And this is easier to compute (costs $\mathcal{O}(mn)$) than the Frobenius norm (which cost $\mathcal{O}(mn \min(m,n))$. If you mean some-other thing, since we cannot read your mind, update your question.